# Second node instance SKPhysicsBody not responding to collision

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I've been trying to create a simple game in SK where the ball would bounce off the tops of trampolines that spawn gradually. Collisions work fine with the first trampoline but I'm having problems registering it when ball hits second trampoline spawned in run-time. Anyone might have a clue what I've been doing wrong?

Here is the code.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var ball: SKShapeNode?
var trampoline: SKShapeNode?
var cam: SKCameraNode?
var hasHit: Bool?
var hasCollided: Bool?
var hasMoved: Bool?

func createBall() {
    ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
    ball?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -600)
    ball?.fillColor = .red
    ball?.strokeColor = .red

    let ballPhysics = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
    ball?.physicsBody = ballPhysics
    ballPhysics.categoryBitMask = 1
    ballPhysics.collisionBitMask = 0
    ballPhysics.contactTestBitMask = 0
    ballPhysics.affectedByGravity = false //NO GRAVITY!
    ballPhysics.isDynamic = true

    addChild(ball!)
}

func createTrampoline(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
    let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 100, height: 20)
    trampoline = SKShapeNode(rect: rect)
    trampoline?.fillColor = .blue
    trampoline?.strokeColor = .blue

    let trampolinePhysics = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 100, height: 20))
    trampoline?.physicsBody = trampolinePhysics
    trampolinePhysics.categoryBitMask = 2
    trampolinePhysics.collisionBitMask = 0
    trampolinePhysics.contactTestBitMask = 1
    trampolinePhysics.affectedByGravity = false //NO GRAVITY!
    trampolinePhysics.isDynamic = true

    addChild(trampoline!)
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    cam = SKCameraNode()
    self.camera = cam
    self.backgroundColor = .darkText
    hasHit = false
    hasCollided = false
    hasMoved = false

    createBall()
    createTrampoline(x: -50, y: -10)

}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touches: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touches.location(in: self)
        let move = SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.1)
        ball?.run(move)
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (!hasMoved!) {
        let vect = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 600)
        ball?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vect)
        ball?.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        hasMoved = true
    }
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
    if (hasHit == true) {
        cam?.position.y = (ball?.position.y)!
    }
}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let vect = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 1500)
    if (((contact.bodyB.node?.position.y)! - (contact.bodyA.node?.position.y)!) > 0) {
        if (!hasCollided!){
            hasHit = true
            hasCollided = true
            print("collision")
            contact.bodyB.applyImpulse(vect)
            createTrampoline(x: -50, y: ((ball?.position.y)! + CGFloat(3000)))
        }
    } else {
        print("bad coll")
        hasCollided = false
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your boolean `hasCollided` is hurting you.  After you make your first contact,  you will never be able to make your second contact because you never set it to false.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon But shouldn't contact be still registered? The `hasCollided` is only in the condition for a case... The problem is that `didBegin` is not even called at the second collision.

Comment: Did you verify it is not being called by printing immediately after didbegin?  The other issue could be that bodyB is not guaranteed to be be ball, so you may have trampoline.y - ball.y which is opposite of ball.y - trampoline.y.  You need to guarantee your order here.  Easiest way to do that is to say `let bodyA = bodyA.categoryBitMask < bodyB.categoryBitmask ? bodyA : bodyB;let bodyB = bodyA.categoryBitMask < bodyB.categoryBitmask ? bodyB : bodyA`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yes, I verified.. the `didBegin` is not called at all. The new trampoline node is visibly added and registered because the node count increases, but it acts like it's not really there. The ball just passes through it with nothing to say.

Comment: Nothing in the code provided is going to cause your body to not exist, nor have the ball pass through it without didbegin firing. If it works on the first it should work on the second

Comment: Although the actual body may not be where your trampoline is, that is probably your problem.  The rect needs to be relative to the node, not absolute to the scene.  Use position to set your nodes location.

Comment: That didn't occur to me, I'll try to look into it. Thank you.

Comment: you can do `view.showPhysics = true` to see where your physics body are

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That helped a lot - it looks like the physics body for the second trampoline is assigned to the first one, even though the trampoline variable has had new rectangle assigned to it.

Comment: Shouldnt be, you are creating a new node.  The physicsBody is wrapped around the center of your node, but your lines do not cross the center.  make sure you are doing `let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20)`, then `trampoline?.position = CGPoint(x:x,y:y)` after you create the new one.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I managed to fix it with giving physicsBody rectangle a centre, but your suggested approach seems to be more elegant and less erroneous. That did it, thanks again.